# Everybody edits looping help C#

Tags: computer-science

I am using C# to make a bot for a game called 'Everybody Edits', using PlayerIOClient.dll, and i was wondering how i could make my bot clear the top three rows of the world, and make them just the empty block, which the block id  is 0. For my world, the worldWidth is 25, and the worldHeight is 25 (blocks) and i just dont know how to make it do that. I was thinking of doing this (worldKey is pretty much the core of the editing:

```
for (int w = 0; w < worldWidth - 1; w++)
{
    for int (h = 0; h < worldHeight - 22; h++)
    {
        build(0, w, h, 0);
    }
}
```

Would this work? By the way i am a beginner programmer, and sorry if this isnt thorough enough i just dont know how to ask it. Please revise it/the whole thing if you need to thanks for your help :D

Comment: What is the site of this "Everybody Edits" game?

Answer (score 0):

well because you want to clear the top 3 world then you would program this code here into a button...

```
     {
        Random r = new Random();
        {
            if (bx >= width)
            {
                if (by >= height)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    bx = 0;
                    by++;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < (how many time you want this to happen, 75 for the first three rows because 25 times 3 is 75... lol); i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                con.Send(worldkey, 0, bx + 1, by + 1 , 0);
                bx++;
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope This Helps... my username in ee1 is famey